# Remove file starting with double ampersand and exclamation

Tags: bash, unix, vim, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a file called `&& !!`

How do I delete this file?

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    && !!
```

```
rm -- "&& !!"
```

Result:

> rm: cannot remove '&& git st': No such file or directory

As you've might guessed, `git st` is my way of `git status`.

How did I get here?

1. Open Vim
2. `:e && !!`
3. `:wq`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `rm -- "&& !!"` attempt failed because history expansion replaced `!!` by the previously executed command. You can avoid this by quoting your file name in single quotes since you don't need the content to be expanded:

```
rm -- '&& !!'
```

History expansion has tripped me up more often than I liked and I never found a use for the feature, so I chose to disable it by adding `set +H` to my `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 5):

Use single quotes like this: `rm -- '&& !!'`.

Double quotes expand their contents.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest finding the inodes using

```
ls -i
```

then using the following to remove the affected files, where $inum is the inode number obtained from the listing. This will get rid of files with any weird characters.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -inum $inum -delete
```

Be careful of ampersands since sometimes hackers leave files with those characters that have commands in the filename in the hope that somebody will accidentally execute them,.